# How to display ancient egyptian hieroglyphs in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

What font should be used?
How can I display a specific hieroglyph?
Do .NET controls support this? Is there some limitation in .NET char and string types?

Comment: You may want to clarify whether this is for Windows forms or WPF. Both are fundamentally different regarding text rendering.

Answer (score 5):

The Egyptian hieroglyphs are in the extended version of Unicode: the [Supplementary Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) (SMP). You can find a full reference [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U13000.pdf). So the first hieroglyph starts at 0x13000 (hex).

The recommended font is: [NewGardiner](https://mjn.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/egyptian/fonts/newgardiner.html). Install the SMP version of the font. I set this font to my RichTextBox or Label in a C# Windows Forms application. Font size 30 makes the hieroglyphs readable.

Setting an hieroglyph to a `char` is impossible in .NET. This is because the `char` is not designed to hold the values that we need. `Char` is 16 bit in .NET and we want to refer to 0x1300 hex (77824 decimal). `String` on the other hand can handle this, but we need to use the \U (not \u) and create a 32bit character (note the leading zeros). The following code displays the first hieroglyph in the table.

```
string single_character = "\U00013000";
label1.Text = single_character;
```

So now we have our single character (glyph) encoded as 4 bytes instead of 2. 
Also two hieroglyphs will be encoded like this:

```
string two_characters = "\U00013000\U00013010";
```

[image: Ancient Egyptian Hieroglyphs on .NET]

If you get an error setting the NewGardiner font then restart Visual Studio and try to change it again.

**Update:** I created an example .NET project:
https://github.com/toncho11/EgyptianHieroglyphsProcessing

Comment: "Extended version of Unicode" is nonsense. There are numbered Unicode versions, but your term doesn't mean anything. What you probably mean is that hieroglyphs are not in the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) of Unicode (there are 17 planes after all).